# How to give two different function to the same button when it's located on different screen?

Tags: react-native, use-state, flatlist

**page 1**

My FlatList looks like below.

```
    <FlatList
      ref={flatListRef}
      contentContainerStyle={{
        paddingBottom: 20,
      }}
      keyboardDismissMode={true}
      showsVerticalScrollIndicator={false}
      data={state}
      keyExtractor={(comment) => "" + comment.id}
      renderItem={renderComment}
    />
```

and rendercomment looks like below.
As you can see, it goes to CommentRow screen with data.

```
  const renderComment = ({ item: commentsRow }) => {
    const { comments } = getValues();
    return (
      <CommentRow
        commentsRow={commentsRow}
        photoId={route?.params?.photoId}
        updatedComments={comments}
        textRef={textRef}
      />
    );
  };
```

And when I press `confirm` button, it can `create` the comment.

```
    <ConfirmButton onPress={handleSubmit(onValid)}>
      <ConfirmText>확인</ConfirmText>
```

**page 2**

If we go to `CommentRow` screen.
if I press Edit button, i want to edit my comment.

```
      <TouchableOpacity onPress={onEditClick}>
        <WriteComment>수정</WriteComment>
```

But Problem is when I press `edit` button, I need to change the payload of comment with the same button which is confirm button of `Comment`.
So when i press confirm button, it doesn't `edit` comment but it `create` comment.

If this components are in one page, then I can use `useState` in order to distinguish edit button from confirm button.
But since they are in two screen separately, I can't send the info that this is edit button `from page 2 to page 1`.
because flatlist only pass data `from page 1 to page 2`.

I've struggled with this issue for 1 week :(
have you any idea for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could pass a callback function from page 1 to page 2 as follows.

```js
 const onUpdateComment = React.useCallback((newComment) => {
    // update state here for setting the new comment
 }, [whatever you need here])

 const renderComment = ({ item: commentsRow }) => {
    const { comments } = getValues();
    return (
      <CommentRow
        commentsRow={commentsRow}
        photoId={route?.params?.photoId}
        comments={comments}
        updateComments={onUpdateComment} // this has changed on page 1
        textRef={textRef}
      />
    );
  };
```

On page 2 you can use the passed callback function.

```js
const onEditClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  // do the other stuff
  updateComments(newComment) // this is the callback function passed in the updateComments prop of CommentRow in page 1
}, [whatever you need here])
<TouchableOpacity onPress={onEditClick}>
```

Comment: I think I need to pass data from page 2 to page1. but here you also pass data from page 1 to page2, and why should we use `useCallback` here? can you explain me more?

Comment: No, page 2 get a callback function passed from page 1. Whenever page 2 calls the callback the state in page 1 changes. Have you tried to integrate my code in yours?

Comment: ok I understand. thanks. now I know I can change state thru `useCallback`. And can I also send data through useCallback? can you show me more example for data passing? :)

Comment: I want to send data named `commentId` from page 2 to page 1. So I try this way: `const onEditClick = React.useCallback(() => {
  updateComments(commentId)
}`

Comment: and from page 1: I get data this way `const onUpdateComment = React.useCallback(
    (commentId) => {
      setEdit(true);
      console.log(commentId);
    },
    [edit, comments]
  );`

Comment: but it seems it doesn't work.

Comment: This is not quite correct. We use the function `onUpdateComment` as a callback function that we pass as a prop to another component. The `React.useCallback` creates a memoized version of the function that we put inside it. It only changes if its dependencies changes.

Comment: See [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback)

Comment: so in this case, can't I send `commentId` from page 2 to page 1? I'm a beginner sorry :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242177/discussion-between-david-scholz-and-hyejung).